# What are the benefits of the Kafka REST Proxy API?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

I do not know the advantages of the Kafka REST Proxy API.
It's a REST API, so I know it's handy for administration.
Why do people use the Kafka REST Proxy API?
Is it burdensome to add a Maven dependency on a producer or a consumer?

Also, I know that the kafka client has better performance.

Comment: Pretend that you are using some obscure language without a Kafka client library but do have HTTP libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't use it for performance

1. Administration - You can make a single ACL for only REST Proxy communications
2. Integrate with non-JVM languages that have no Kafka libraries. For example, client side Javascript

Comment: Thank you!
Could you answer the link below? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097721/confluents-kafka-rest-proxy-vs-kafka-client